# Database design of keywords to product mapping for searching purpose?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to build a search functionality where a user can search products on the platform

**case 1:** A product can be searched by many keywords.

**case 2:** A keyword can be mapped to multiple products.

its like a many-to-many relationship between product and keyword

**current approach:**

```
    productTable: id(primary key)(int)
                  name(string)

    keywordTable: id(primary key)(int)
                  name(string)

    keywordProductMapping: id(primary key)(int)
                           product_id #FK productTable (id) 
                           keyword_id #FK keywordTable(id)
```

**Problem statement:** If I would have millions of products and a product have say 20-30 keywords then `keywordProductMapping` will become too large
and querying to this table can very slow

any better approach for `keywordToProductMapping`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is right - a proper way to implement an `M:N` in SQL is using an intermediate table with 2 FKs. A few points though:

1. This will not be slow. Int columns are very small, so even very long tables will fit in memory fine and will perform well. After all, tens of millions rows is OK for most common database engines.
2. Get rid of the `id` on `keywordProductMapping`. This is a useless column on an `M:N` relation. PK should be defined as `product_id,keyword_id`. This way the table will be even smaller.
3. Don't forget indexes on FKs.

Another option is to use a dedicated system for keywords (i.e. ElasticSearch) that could perform better on large sets and will allow for some potential growth (partial matches, phrases, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems completely fine with relational database. If you are using this for autocomplete feature and traffic in your site is high , this will lead to large number of database hits , and could lead to higher latency , depending upon mysql engine you are using .

You should first decide , whats your basic requirement with design , can you compromise on latency , or on consistency .

If you want low latency and synonyms kind of functionality , this kind of functionality comes pre build with nosql databases such as Solr , Elastic Search . These will actually help you fetch the data faster , thereby reducing the latency . But implementing this will require a bit of maintenance , indexing the data on timely basis .

So you should spend some amount of time in deciding the design according to your needs . 
Hope this helps !